# Changing Period to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

### My goal is to convert period to datetime.

**If Life Was Easy:**

```
master_df = master_df['Month'].to_datetime()
```

**Back Story:**

I built a new dataFrame that originally summed the monthly totals and made a 'Month' column by converting a timestamp to period. Now I want to convert that time period back to a timestamp so that I can create plots using matplotlib.

[image]

**I have tried following:**

- Reading the docs for [Period.to_timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html#pandas.Period.to_timestamp).
- Converting to a string and then back to datetime. Still keeps the period issue and won't convert.
- Following a couple similar questions in Stackoverflow but could not seem to get it to work.

**A simple goal would be to plot the following:**

```
plot.bar(m_totals['Month'], m_totals['Showroom Visits']);
```

**This is the error I get if I try to use a period dtype in my charts**

```
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value.
```

This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units.

### Additional Material:

Code I used to create the `Month` column (where period issue was created):

`master_df['Month'] = master_df['Entry Date'].dt.to_period('M')`

Codes I used to group to monthly totals:

```
m_sums = master_df.groupby(['DealerName','Month']).sum().drop(columns={'Avg. Response Time','Closing Percent'})

m_means = master_df.groupby(['DealerName','Month']).mean()
m_means = m_means[['Avg. Response Time','Closing Percent']]

m_totals = m_sums.join(m_means)
m_totals.reset_index(inplace=True)
m_totals
```

**Resulting DataFrame:**

[image]

Comment: Could you include an example of the `month` column? It would significantly help

Comment: I guess you would want to make your case reproducible by providing the code that creates a period column, tries to convert it to datetime, show the output from which it becomes clear in how far conversion has failed. (also see [mcve])

Comment: Have you tried `m_totals.plot.bar(x='Nonth', y='Showroom Visits')`?

Comment: I have added additional information, to help illustrate the issue better. @CodeDifferent that did chart information, though I still would like to try to figure out the original issue of how to convert a period dtype to datetime dtype

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, would you consider the updated question reasonable? I want to make it easy as possible but don't want to add more than needed as it *seems* that it is more of a snytax issue on my end. Thanks for sharing the article.

Comment: Anyone wanting to help here would need to spend significant effort creating the data for themselves, with the risk that it's not actually reproducing the problem. Maybe [sscce.org](http://sscce.org) makes that clearer.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to cast the period type to string then to datetime. Just could not go straight from period to datetime.

```
m_totals['Month'] = m_totals['Month'].astype(str)
m_totals['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(m_totals['Month'])
m_totals.dtypes
```

[image]

I wish I did not get downvoted for not providing the entire dataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution is to use [`to_timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html). For example: `m_totals['Month'] = m_totals['Month'].dt.to_timestamp()`

Answer (score 0):

First change it to str then to date

```
index=pd.period_range(start='1949-01',periods=144 ,freq='M')
type(index)
#changing period to date
index=index.astype(str)
index=pd.to_datetime(index)
df.set_index(index,inplace=True)
type(df.index)
df.info()
```